# how to put php variable as an element of list in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a project that will display a bar chart. The bar chart is working perfectly but when I try to pass an integer php variable to javascript variable and add the variable as an element of a list isn't working. below is my code. I don't know what is wrong with my source code. I spend several hours finding for solution online but I don't get any.

Looking forward to see your response.

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

 #container {
 height: 400px; 
 min-width: 310px; 
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
    </style>

 <?php

 //my php variable
 $ab=6;

 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 //assign the php variable to javascript variable
 var za = <?php echo $ab; ?>;


 $(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({
 chart: {
 type: 'column',
 options3d: {
 enabled: true,
 alpha: 10,
 beta: 25,
 depth: 70
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: '3D chart with null values'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Notice the difference between a 0 value and a null point'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 25
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: Highcharts.getOptions().lang.shortMonths
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sales',
        // I'm putting the variable as an element below, but it's not working 
        data: [za, 3, null, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3]
    }]
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work just fine. Have you checked what the *output* of the PHP is?

Comment: Assuming the file is saved as php and executed as php it should work. If you just saved it as .html then not

Comment: If I access the page in browser am just seeing blank page (i.e a page without any contain) but if I replace the 'za' variable in a data list with a number the bar chart is showing on the page

Comment: What is $ab? Perhaps it is not what you think? If string that is not a number you need `var za = "<?php echo $ab; ?>";` - the console should also be checked

Comment: i checked your code in my local and it work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, you should avoid interacting with javascript in this way.  PHP works better when you're interacting with HTML, and let javascript be separate (this goes halfway towards using a true templating system, which you should do):

```
<?php
// page setup goes up here:
$ab = 6; // name your variables at little more descriptively, I don't know what this does
?>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container { height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            console.log($('#ab-variable').val());
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 10,
                        beta: 25,
                        depth: 70
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '3D chart with null values'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Notice the difference between a 0 value and a null point'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        depth: 25
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: Highcharts.getOptions().lang.shortMonths
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                       text: null
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Sales',
                    // We're referencing our hidden field in the HTML
                    data: [$('#ab-variable').val(), 3, null, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <!-- we're including our variable here, in HTML, rather than in the javascript -->
    <input type="hidden" id="ab-variable" value="<?= $ab; ?>">

    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</body>
```

... you can then look int the HTML and see that your hidden field has the correct value.  If it's still not working, then you've got a problem with your javascript setup using `highcharts`.

If you write your code this way, you get the added benefit of being able to create a separate javascript file that will be cached at the client and they won't have to download it every time.

As is, it doesn't look like there's any *inherent* problem with your code, but re-factoring (when it's warranted) can sometimes suss out little bugs.  To confirm that this code should work the way you want, I've added a `console.log()` call to ensure that your javascript can see your variable.  To see anything more than that you'll have to provide a link to your page so we can see any errors that might be popping up.

Comment: Great! If it solved your problem, consider accepting the answer so that it's obvious to other people that you've been helped.